# Any way to bypass php login page? Testing SQLi on my Damn Vulnerable Web App (DVWA)

Tags: sql-injection

I'm using Damn Vulnerable Web App (DVWA) and I'm following guides and tutorials on how to perform SQL injection. However, the problem is that I don't believe any of the tools I would prefer to use would work, considering the DVWA page requires a login first.

Without authenticating, every page redirects you back to /login.php to log in first. Is there any way possible to somehow modify this to work regardless of being logged in or out?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use your sql injection tactics on the login form itself and create your own working login, or try to first find a working login by other means and use that login to get to other pages for the sql injection attacks.

Since this app is deliberately built to be vulnerable, the login page itself is likely vulnerable.

Alternatively, as the app is open source, you might modify it yourself to remove the login requirement.

Comment: Understandable, and thanks for your input. Although the login page may be vulnerable, I would prefer to focus on this much later. The tutorials and guides I am following are specifically targeting sites that are assumed to not require authentication prior to accessing.

Comment: Also, the portion that I want to fool with is beyond the login page unfortunately.